# PHP: add array value into <option>

Tags: php, html-select

I am looking for a way to create

```
 <option>.Name1.</option>
<option>.OtherName.</option>
```

so on for every top value, reason to think how to extract the array value, without to know the name (Name1, OtherName, etc, that values will come dynamic). For print_r or var_dump you will see the below structure:

```
array (
  'Name1' => 
  array (
    'diametru' => 
    array (
      0 => 15,
      7 => 16,
    ),
    'latime' => 
    array (
      0 => 6,
      9 => 5,
    ),   
  ),
  'OtherName' => 
  array (
    'diametru' => 
    array (
      0 => 16,
      2 => 17     
    ),
    'latime' => 
    array (
      0 => 6,
      1 => 7,
      10 => 5,
      35 => 8,
    ),   
  ),
.........
)
```

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: what have you try so far?

Comment: Hint: have a look at [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function.

Comment: I would like to create a html select and for every "option" to have that values from the array structure you see above.

Comment: There is no need to repeat more or less exactly what you already said in your question in a comment. You were asked what you have _tried_ so far, so answer that please.

Comment: You are not making a lot of sense here, even on your second atempt at this question. Can you at least show us an example of the output you would like to generate please

Comment: Can you give the expected result for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$array = [
    'Name1' => [
        'diametru' => [7,6]
    ],
    'othername' => []
];
$output = array_keys($array);
$option = '';
foreach ($output as $val) {
    $option .= "<option>$val</option>";
}
print_r($option);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know why your sample works but my real array not? http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/allMarks.php  Error: "array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array" and "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @Gafwebmaster it works for me. Actually, I have tried with your actual array https://3v4l.org/eO3Kh

Answer (score 2):

you can just use Foearch :

```
<select>
<?php 
 foreach($array as $keyname=> $list)
{

echo '<option value="'.$keyname.'">'.$keyname.'</option>'; 
}
 ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have many way to do it :

```
$var = [
  'Name1' => [
    'diametru' => [
      0 => 15,
      7 => 16,
    ],
    'latime' => [
      0 => 6,
      9 => 5,
    ],   
  ],
  'OtherName' => [
    'diametru' => [
      0 => 16,
      2 => 17     
    ],
    'latime' => [
      0 => 6,
      1 => 7,
      10 => 5,
      35 => 8,
    ],   
  ]
];

foreach ($var as $index => $value) {
    echo "<option>$index</option>";
}

foreach (array_keys($var) as $index) {
    echo "<option>$index</option>";
}
```

Comment: I recieve in my error_log: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: When you copy past my code ? before your loop please `var_dump` your variable and confirm is really array.